# Delete all but one chart series for all charts

Tags: excel, charts, vba

Excel keeps crashing when I try to delete the second to last series left on the chart (last series I want to delete). I want to loop through all charts on one worksheet and delete vertical line data series at specific x values. See below script I am using to delete each series:

```
Sub delete40()
Dim mychartobjects As ChartObject
Dim mysrs As Series

With activesheet
    For Each mychartobject In .ChartObjects
        For Each mysrs In mychartobject.chart.SeriesCollection
            If mysrs.Name = "40" Then
                mysrs.delete
            End If
        Next mysrs
    Next mychartobject
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you loop if you know the series name?

Comment: I want to loop through all charts on a given worksheet and delete all series with specific names on every chart. Excel only seems to crash when I add more than 3 series to delete, each with the same script as above (named 40, 80, 180, 200).

Comment: FWIW, your code works fine in my tests. No crashing of Excel for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not require a loop.

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("40").Delete
```

works just fine for me. Or, to put it in your context

```
Sub delete40()
Dim mychartobjects As ChartObject
Dim mysrs As Series

With ActiveSheet
    For Each mychartobject In .ChartObjects
        mychartobject.Chart.FullSeriesCollection("40").Delete
    Next mychartobject
End With
End Sub
```